# Caching Marking Algorithms Analysis

Tags: algorithm

I'm having a little bit of problems to understand the analysis about the marking algorithms made in the Kleinberg Tardos "Algoritms Design" book.

In the chapter about Randomization, in particular in the section about Randomized Caching (13.8) the book present a particular class of algorithms called Marking Algorithms that can be used to manage the cache of the system.
This types of algorithms take as input a sequence $\sigma$ of requests for memory items, and process this requests using different phases. Each phase is defined as follow:

```
Each memory item can be either marked or unmarked 
At the beginning of the phase, all items are unmarked 
On a request to item s: 
    Mark s 
    If s is in the cache, then evict nothing
    Else s is not in the cache:
       If all items currently in the cache are marked then 
           Declare the phase over 
           Processing of s is deferred to start of next phase
       Else evict an unmarked item from the cache 
       Endif
    Endif
```

Now during the analysis of the algorithm the book say that:

> To make the analysis easier to discuss, we are going to “pad” the sequence σ both at the beginning and the end with some extra requests [...]   we imagine a “phase 0” that takes place before the ﬁrst phase, in which all the items initially in the cache are requested once. 
>   [...]
>    We also imagine that the ﬁnal phase r ends with an epilogue in which every item currently in the cache of the optimal algorithm is requested twice in roundrobin fashion

Where the optimal algorithm is the hypotethical algorithm that incurs in the minum number of misses for a given sequence σ.

I am having problem to understand why the book make this assumption. 
In particular the book in the following part of the same section states that:

> In each phase, σ contains accesses to exactly k distinct items. The subsequent phase begins with an access to a different (k+1)st item.
>
> The marking algorithm incurs at most k misses per phase, for a total of at most kr misses over all r phases.

Now the sequence that is taken into consideration is probably (at least for what I have undestood) the padded one, but why to use the padded sequence instead of of a normale sequence σ ??

There are special cases to take into consideration if I used the same tecnique to demonstrate that it works also for a non padded sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but why to use the padded sequence instead of of a normale sequence σ

I'd say it's just mathematical trick. You need more or less concrete time for initial cache fulfillment. Now padded sequence clearly states that it does fulfillment in 0 phase and cares less about what happened before that. Otherwise you'd need to think over and over when and why some particular item got to cache.

For similar reason you may need epilogue. To be honest, I do not know why exactly, but you should see references to epilogue in algorithm proofing.

Essentially you can count bare sequence and padded sequence. From parts of proofing you quoted I see that author found somewhat exact number of accesses/misses. It's easier to calculate "misses" with padded sequence, as it is in controllable state. With long enough sequence padding affection is neglectible, but without it? Well, without it you have quite unsteady range of "misses" that can't be precisely counted. And without precision in calculations we supposedly can't proof algorithm preformance.